# Integrar sdk payu laravel

Tags: php, laravel, payu

En la pagina de payu hay un paquete sdk para integrar en mi laravel 5.6 pero no se cómo o dónde almacenarlo.

Esto es lo que encuentro en su documentación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes descargar el `SDK`, descomprimirlo y añadirlo a algún directorio de tu proyecto. Por ejemplo, si lo pones dentro del directorio `/app`, te debería quedar algo así:

```
- app
--- Http
--- Providers
--- lib  <--------------- librería de PayU
----- PayU
------- api
--------- exceptions
--------- resources
--------- util
- bootstrap
- config
- database
- ...
- ...
```

Luego, debes de configurar tus credenciales en la configuración de `PayU`:

**/app/lib/PayU.php**

```
/**
 * The method invocation is for testing purposes
 */
public static $isTest = false; // <--------

/**
 * The merchant API key
 */
public static  $apiKey = "XXXXX"; // <--------

/**
 * The merchant API Login
 */
public static  $apiLogin = "XXXXX"; // <--------

/**
 * The merchant Id
 */
public static  $merchantId = "XXXXX"; // <--------
```

(*) Reemplazar `"XXXXX"` con tus credenciales.

PD: Como recomendación, deberías hacer referencia a variables de entorno alojadas en `.env`.

Ya con esto podrías utilizar la librería. Para manejo y guías, consulta la [documentación](http://developers.payulatam.com/es/sdk/payments.html) de PayU.

Comment: @JhonBernal creo que eso se refiere a como estás utilizando la variable que quieres referenciar. Por ejemplo en vez de hacer esto: `$a = ['hola'];` estás haciendo `[hola]`. Revisa esta pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941169/what-does-the-php-error-message-notice-use-of-undefined-constant-mean

Comment: @JhonBernal por cierto, te aconsejo eliminar ese app_id/secret  de tu comentario (por temas de seguridad)

Comment: si lo que quiero es utilizar ya con laravel creando la function y todo como para empezar seria crear usuario

Comment: el agregar las el orden que me indico resulto gracias